# Using pip with venv

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

This is my current set up for python and pip:

`~$python --version`>>>Python 3.7.7

`~$pip --version`>>>pip 22.0.3 from c:\users\rmuir\folder\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

`~$which python`>>>/c/Users/rmuir/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python

`~$which pip`>>>/c/Users/rmuir/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/Scripts/pip

Then  I create a venv `python -m venv venv` and
enter the .venv `source venv/Scripts/activate`

From my understanding pip is then installed into that environment according to the global python version. This pip version is lower than my current global pip, so I want to upgrade the pip inside the venv but it is saying it is already satisfied and then references the lower version.

`python --version`>>>Python 3.7.7 (venv)

`pip --version`>>>pip 19.2.3 from c:\users\rmuir\folder\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)(venv)

`~$which python`>>>/c/Users/rmuir/folder/\Users\rmuir<folder>.venv/Scripts/python(venv)

`~$which pip`>>>/c/Users/rmuir/folder/\Users\rmuir\folder\venv/Scripts/pip (venv)

Some of those returns look off to me, specifically the `pip --version` ran outside of a venv returns a version upgraded in another venv?

But I digress...I want to upgrade the pip inside the newly created venv so I run...

`$python -m pip install --upgrade pip`>>>Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\rmuir\folder\folder\venv\lib\site-packages (19.2.3)(venv)

Any help would be appreciated. I was originally thinking the path variables were off, I have thought about uninstalling python and pip and reinstalling. Python should probably be under /Program files instead of AppData but I don't know if that is a root issue or just a better practice.

Please let me know what you think or if further info is needed.

Comment: Can you double-check this line? `~$pip --version>>>pip 22.0.3 from c:\users\rmuir\folder\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)`. That has the same path as your pip within your venv.

Comment: @Jeff  I thought that was strange as well, that it was referencing another venv pip even when I wasn't in one. (I believe that is a venv from another project). I didn't think about it but I went to my 'select interpreter' in vs code, would it cause an issue if an interpreter of another venv was selected even if all venvs are ```deactivate```in bash terminal?  In any case i select the global interpreter and then ran ```pip --version``` and it returned fatal error in launcher and references a pithon.exe from another venv and pip.exe from \Roaming\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe